# C++ Code Translation with Eigen Matrix Library

Tags: c#, c++, eigen

I have the following code I am translating to C# from C++ which is using Eigen.

```
template <typename PointT> inline unsigned int
pcl::SamplingSurfaceNormal<PointT>::computeMeanAndCovarianceMatrix (const pcl::PointCloud<PointT> &cloud,
                                                                    Eigen::Matrix3f &covariance_matrix,
                                                                    Eigen::Vector4f &centroid)
{
    // create the buffer on the stack which is much faster than using cloud.points[indices[i]] and centroid as a buffer
    Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, 9, Eigen::RowMajor> accu = Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, 9, Eigen::RowMajor>::Zero ();
    std::size_t point_count = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cloud.points.size (); i++)
    {
        if (!isFinite (cloud[i]))
        {
          continue;
        }

        ++point_count;
        accu [0] += cloud[i].x * cloud[i].x;
        accu [1] += cloud[i].x * cloud[i].y;
        accu [2] += cloud[i].x * cloud[i].z;
        accu [3] += cloud[i].y * cloud[i].y; // 4
        accu [4] += cloud[i].y * cloud[i].z; // 5
        accu [5] += cloud[i].z * cloud[i].z; // 8
        accu [6] += cloud[i].x;
        accu [7] += cloud[i].y;
        accu [8] += cloud[i].z;
    }

    accu /= static_cast<float> (point_count);
    centroid[0] = accu[6]; centroid[1] = accu[7]; centroid[2] = accu[8];
    centroid[3] = 0;
    covariance_matrix.coeffRef (0) = accu [0] - accu [6] * accu [6];
    covariance_matrix.coeffRef (1) = accu [1] - accu [6] * accu [7];
    covariance_matrix.coeffRef (2) = accu [2] - accu [6] * accu [8];
    covariance_matrix.coeffRef (4) = accu [3] - accu [7] * accu [7];
    covariance_matrix.coeffRef (5) = accu [4] - accu [7] * accu [8];
    covariance_matrix.coeffRef (8) = accu [5] - accu [8] * accu [8];
    covariance_matrix.coeffRef (3) = covariance_matrix.coeff (1);
    covariance_matrix.coeffRef (6) = covariance_matrix.coeff (2);
    covariance_matrix.coeffRef (7) = covariance_matrix.coeff (5);

    return (static_cast<unsigned int> (point_count));
}
```

In Eigens documentation, I can find *NO WHERE* what it means to call `someMatix3f.coeffRef(x)` or `someMatrix3f.coeff(x)` on a 2D matrix. What do these operators do?

Note, I have seen the documentation (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a72e84dc1bb573ad8ecc9109fbbc1b63b) and even with my PhD in mathematics, it means nothing to me.

I have attempted the translation using `MathNET.Numerics` and this method is

```
private int ComputeMeanAndCovarianceMatrix(
    PointCloud cloud,
    Matrix<float> covariance_matrix,
    MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector<float> centroid)
{
    int point_count = 0;
    Matrix<float> accu = Matrix<float>.Build.DenseOfRowMajor(1, 9, Enumerable.Repeat(0.0f, 9));

    for (int i = 0; i < cloud.Vertices.Length; ++i)
    {
        //if (!isFinite(cloud.Vertices[i].Point.))
        //{
        //  continue;
        //}

        ++point_count;
        accu[0, 0] += cloud.Vertices[i].Point.X * cloud.Vertices[i].Point.X;
        accu[0, 1] += cloud.Vertices[i].Point.X * cloud.Vertices[i].Point.Y;
        accu[0, 2] += cloud.Vertices[i].Point.X * cloud.Vertices[i].Point.Z;
        accu[0, 3] += cloud.Vertices[i].Point.Y * cloud.Vertices[i].Point.Y; // 4
        accu[0, 4] += cloud.Vertices[i].Point.Y * cloud.Vertices[i].Point.Z; // 5
        accu[0, 5] += cloud.Vertices[i].Point.Z * cloud.Vertices[i].Point.Z; // 8
        accu[0, 6] += cloud.Vertices[i].Point.X;
        accu[0, 7] += cloud.Vertices[i].Point.Y;
        accu[0, 8] += cloud.Vertices[i].Point.Z;
    }
    accu /= point_count;

    centroid[0] = accu[0, 6];
    centroid[1] = accu[0, 7];
    centroid[2] = accu[0, 8];
    centroid[3] = 0;

    covariance_matrix[0, 0] = accu[0, 0] - accu[0, 6] * accu[0, 6];
    covariance_matrix[0, 1] = accu[0, 1] - accu[0, 6] * accu[0, 7];
    covariance_matrix[0, 2] = accu[0, 2] - accu[0, 6] * accu[0, 8];
    covariance_matrix[1, 1] = accu[0, 3] - accu[0, 7] * accu[0, 7];
    covariance_matrix[1, 2] = accu[0, 4] - accu[0, 7] * accu[0, 8];
    covariance_matrix[2, 2] = accu[0, 5] - accu[0, 8] * accu[0, 8];
    covariance_matrix[1, 0] = covariance_matrix[0, 1];
    covariance_matrix[2, 0] = covariance_matrix[0, 2];
    covariance_matrix[2, 1] = covariance_matrix[1, 2];

    return point_count;
}
```

Look right?

Comment: Yeah, but what on earth does `

This is an overloaded version of DenseCoeffsBase<Derived,WriteAccessors>::coeffRef(Index) const provided to by-pass the creation of an evaluator of the expression, thus saving compilation efforts.

See DenseCoeffsBase<Derived,WriteAccessors>::coeffRef(Index) const for details.` mean?

Comment: I would like to know functionally what it get from the matrix. I assume it assumes the matrix is RowMajor and retrieve the values accordingly, but this is written absolutely no where as far as I can tell and I have looked through the source code which is equally opaque...

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are porting it to C# instead of calling it as a dll?

Comment: Yes, I only need a very small subsection of the code and don't want the overhead of wrapping this class as it has a complex hierarchy of dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coeffRef` just provides access to the underlying data array. Therefore, your translation to `covariance_matrix[i, j]` should be equivalent. Note that the expression `covariance_matrix.coeffRef(k)` just gives the `k`th element in the data array, irrelevant of storage order. And yes, it would have made more sense for the original code to use `coeffRef(i,j)`, IMO.

The reason this would be there (I'm guessing here. ggael and chtz will probably be able to confirm/refute) is that is that Eigen uses a lot of expression templates to determine when and how to evaluate parts of expressions. Some are dependent on storage order of matrices, some aren't. In cases where it's not dependent on storage order (e.g. scalar * matrix) being able to "short circuit" the expression reduces the amount of steps the compiler has to go through in order to decide how to evaluate a given expression can reduce compile times. If we explicitly state `coeffRef`, then we tell the compiler that we're talking about a concrete object with storage, and not an expression.